# Default Asp.Net Core web template comes with error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

Can anyone explain why the default Asp.Net Web Application template, with Individual user identification, comes with an error in the Manage Controller?

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SendVerificationEmail(IndexViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
        }

        var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
        var callbackUrl = Url.EmailConfirmationLink(user.Id, code, Request.Scheme);
        var email = user.Email;
        await _emailSender.SendEmailConfirmationAsync(email, callbackUrl);

        StatusMessage = "Verification email sent. Please check your email.";
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
```

In this code line;

```
return View(model);
```

[image: VS Inspection of red squiggly under View]

View is Red, because there is no SendVerificationEmail view. Is this normal? Can this be resolved?

I could specify a view to route to like

```
 if (!ModelState.IsValid)
 {
     return View(nameof(Index),model);
 }
```

but is that really where the Asp.Net team intended this to go from here?

Comment: And what exactly is the error?

Comment: @Jerodev...You read the post?  View is Red, because there is no SendVerificationEmail view. Is this normal? Can this be resolved?

Comment: @dinotom can you please let me know from where you have open "Inspection options" dialog?

Comment: @programtreasures...from clicking on the red light bulb to the left of the code

Comment: Is this a ReSharper tool? It does look like a bug to me.

Comment: @Calc yes it is a resharper tool..I can just redirect it. Where do you think they intended it to go, Index?

Comment: It looks that way (with the `IndexViewModel`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears, and is agreed to by a few people I've shown this to, that it may be a bug.
Not sure how to report that but given the model is an IndexViewModel, I fixed it by routing the return result to the index view.

```
 if (!ModelState.IsValid)
 {
     return View(nameof(Index),model);
 }
```

Not sure if that is where the Asp.Net default application team meant for this to re-route but that's the fix(kludge) I'm going with. Any better solutions, please comment.